# creating a method for associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to be able to sort my accounts by some criteria based on an instance method. This is a method I want to use for this:

```
def sorted
  partition { |account| account.is_referral?}.each do |a| 
    a.sort! {|a,b| a.label <=> b.label}
  end.flatten
end
```

where `is_referral?` and `label` are both instance methods of `Account` class.

So I could get sorted accounts with `User.first.accounts.sorted`.

I am able to do this if I create a scope that does something and then extend it:

```
scope :filtered, lambda { |filter|
    if filter == Listing::FILTER_INACTIVE
      where("status = ?", Account::STATUS_INACTIVE)
    elsif filter == Account::FILTER_ACTIVE
      where("status = ?", Account::STATUS_ACTIVE)      
    end
  } do
    def sorted
      partition { |account| account.is_referral?}.each do |a| 
        a.sort! {|a,b| a.label <=> b.label}
      end.flatten
    end
  end
```

Now I can use `User.accounts.filtered(Account::FILTER_ACTIVE).sorted`. I figure this is because `scope.class` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `User.first.accounts.class` returns `Array`.

I've also tried this one:

```
scope :sorted, lambda { |object|
  object.partition { |account| account.is_referral?}.each do |a| 
    a.sort! {|a,b| a.label <=> b.label}
  end.flatten
}
```

But this throws `NoMethodError` for `nil.partition`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define proxy methods on associations by doing

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts do
    def sorted
      proxy_target.partition { |account| account.is_referral?}.each do |a| 
           a.sort! {|a,b| a.label <=> b.label}
      end.flatten
    end
  end
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions

Use this with `User.last.accounts(true).sorted` to get the results, because otherwise your association will not be loaded and you will receive empty array as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm however getting empty array as a result. The exact realtion is `has_many :accounts, :through => :calendars`, but no matter where do I define your method ( in `Calendar` or `User`) I get empty array.

Comment: I've discovered why I was getting this and added explanation to your post. Thanks once again.